# Automate replacing failed disk in software RAID

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

Can `mdadm` automatically recognize a plugged disk as a spare, partition it and add?

My config:

```
[root@okvmh2 ~]# lsblk -a
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
+-sda1              8:1    0  513M  0 part
¦ L-md127           9:127  0  513M  0 raid1 /boot
L-sda2              8:2    0  1.8T  0 part
  L-md126           9:126  0  3.7T  0 raid5
    +-centos-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm   /
    +-centos-swap 253:1    0   20G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    L-centos-home 253:2    0  3.6T  0 lvm   /home
```

(same for sdb and sdc; 3 disks total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `mdadm`, it sounds like the answer is "no, you have to do some work".

Further reading:

- [Replacing failed Raid Drive](http://www.kernelhardware.org/replacing-failed-raid-drive/)
- [Tutorials: Replacing A Failed Hard Drive In A Software RAID1 Array>](https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array)
- [mdadm - replacing failed drive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136754)